# Why aren't static assets loading when I access my pyramid app through my computer's IP address?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app that I've been developing and viewing locally through `http://localhost:6543`, which is what the paster docs suggest.  There are various assets, for example `.css` files, available in a `static` directory, which I have made available through `config.add_static_view('static','static')` When I view it through `localhost` everything works fine, my .css files are loaded, and all is well.  However, when I view the app through my computer's hostname/IP address, the static assets aren't loaded.

A freshly-installed Pyramid paster scaffold displays the same behavior.  I've gone through and followed the Pyramid narrative documentation through the step called [viewing the application](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/project.html#viewing-the-application), and everything works as is described.  But change the URL in the location bar from `http://localhost:6543` to `http://my.host.name:6543` and the style sheets don't get loaded.

The assets are available; type `http://my.host.name:6543/static/pylons.css` on a freshly-created Pyramid paster scaffold and you can read the contents of the css, but it's not loaded when the root page is loaded.  Firebug indicates that those resources are requested, but never received.

What's going on here, and how can I make sure that my static assets are loaded when I request them through something other than `localhost`?

**Edit** to add some code.  This is from the Pyramid `starter` paster scaffold, which I haven't modified and which exhibits the same behavior my application does; it can be considered a minimal example.

from package's `__init__.py`:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

complete `views.py`:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.pt')
def my_view(request):
    return {'project':'TestProject'}
```

relevant line from `templates/mytemplate.pt`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/pylons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" 
charset="utf-8" />
```

Where `static/pylons.css` is in the `static` directory under the root.

Again, opening `http://0.0.0.0:6543` in the browser (FF10) works fine, `http://my.host.name:6543` displays the page without style information; but `http://my.host.name:6543/static/pylons.css` gives me the style sheet text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being able to look at your code it's a bit hard to answer this question. My guess based on a similar experience is that you might not be using the static_url method inside your templates. Below is another way to reference static assets in your templates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${request.static_url('app:static/css/app.css')}">
```

Are you using that? Using anything else will certainly cause the behaviour you are seeing.

There seems to be a problem if the application is installed to a path that is not the document route. You can see this discussed [here](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/pull/418).

Comment: I would use relative URLs: `href="/static/pylons.css`, but like you said, without seeing his code I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I thought that since I'm having the same problem with the paster scaffold, posting code wouldn't be necessary as everyone who would be able to help has or can easily get the scaffold. I'll add some code above.

Comment: Is the approved way you mention in the docs somewhere?  I haven't seen it, and have been using relative URLs as Jonathan suggests, which is also what the scaffolds use.

Comment: Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.static_url). It looks like this might be a bug in Pyramid. [Here is a recent pull request that hints at this](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/pull/418) and perhaps the actual explanation for your problem as well.

Comment: Well, now it seems to work, even though I changed nothing.  I even reverted to the revision that was current when I asked this question, and it works.  Thanks for the info, though!

Comment: Strange, they might have backported a fix I guess. Cheers!